# Plotting ellipses from an array

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, ellipse

I'm sure this is a basic question, but I am trying to make a plot of three ellipses from the semi-major axis (a), the semi-minor axis (b) and the angle that the ellipse is rotated (p).

I have a, b, and the rotation stored in three separate arrays
a = [a1,a2,a3], b=[b1,b2,b3] and p=[p1,p2,p3].

I am new to matplotlib and I don't know how to pass these three parameters through to make three separate graphs of ellipses.

Here is my code so far:

```
ellipse_one = [Ellipse(xy= (0,0), width=a_ellipse_one, height=b_ellipse_one, angle = rotation_ellipse_one)   
plt.gca().add_patch(ellipse_one)
ax.add_patch(ellipse_one)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Should all ellipses be in the same figure?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

This creates 3 ellipses in the same figure:

```
for w, h, angle in zip(a, b, p):
    ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(0,0), width=w, height=h, angle=angle)
    ax.add_patch(ellipse)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

To put each ellipse in a separate subplot, do something like this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(a), sharex=True, sharey=True)

for ax, w, h, angle in zip(axes, a, b, p):
    ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(0,0), width=w, height=h, angle=angle)
    ax.add_patch(ellipse)
plt.axis('auto')
plt.show()
```